# Getting to time to change format and save correctly

Tags: grails, simpledateformat

I'm trying to save a time in HH:MM format in my domain but I keep getting errors:

My domain:

```
Date startTime
Date endTime
```

I've tried using DateTime also

My Controller:

```
def save() {

    def ScheduleMain = new ScheduleMain(params)
        //Storing the weeks instances inside an object  def weeks = ScheduleMain.schedules      //check save yes or no rediect  if (!ScheduleMain.save(flush:true)) {       //render("did not save")        render(view: "create", model: [scheduleInstance: ScheduleMain])         return  }       //set up week count     def weekNo = 0      //building up each instance of data - looping each set of week data     weeks.each() {  //setting up a string to access the schedule data from the params for each week     String schedule = "schedules[" + weekNo + "]"
    //sets up an object that stores this weeks data         def scheduleSave = it
        //loop through each schedules data      params.entrySet().findAll {             it.key == schedule          }.each {
                //set up object to allow access to this schedules data      def schedParam = it.value       println ("This is the value of the new param: " + it.value)         println("Weeks Data: " + scheduleSave)
            //loops through each schedules day          it.value.findAll {
        it.key.startsWith('day_')
        }.each {

            //check to see if day_ object is checked - this cascade saves the day_ data
            if(it.value != null){

                 //set up day string e.g. day_Monday
                 String day = it.key
                 //generate a string based on the day string but stripping stripping out day_ e.g. Monday
                 def daySubString = day[4..-1]
                 //builds up string to access the number of messages for the day
                 String noOfMessages = daySubString + "numberOfMessages"
                 //get value of message that day
                 def noOfMessagesValue = schedParam.get(noOfMessages)


                 scheduleSave = scheduleSave
                 .addToScheduleDays(new ScheduleDays(day:daySubString, 
                    startTime: params.startTime().format('HH:mm'), 
                    endTime: params.endTime().format('HH:mm'), 
                    numberOfMessages: noOfMessagesValue))
                 .save(flush:true)
                }

            }

        }

        weekNo++            }       }
```

you'll see I loop round each iteration however I get the error while saving startTime and endTime to the domain. Hopefully that makes sense on what I'm trying to do..

Comment: params.startTime() is your key in the map, not a method right?!

Comment: to be honest I've got a bit lost now.. it should be in the map as I need to save everything cascading across a few tables.

Comment: Its a key in your map, you can just use it like: `params.startTime`

Comment: but then I get told it's not a valid format for the property Date

Comment: error: Property schedules[0].startTime must be a valid Date

Answer (score 0):

> error: Property schedules[0].startTime must be a valid Date

The error is valid because params holds String object of your time. So you need to parse that into date object:

```
scheduleSave = scheduleSave
                 .addToScheduleDays(new ScheduleDays(day:daySubString, 
                    startTime: Date.parse( "HH:mm", params.startTime ).format('HH:mm'), 
                    endTime: Date.parse( "HH:mm", params.endTime ).format('HH:mm') , 
                    numberOfMessages: noOfMessagesValue))
                 .save(flush:true)
                }
```